# pthread mutex without mmap possible?

Tags: memory, pthreads, fork, parent, mmap

On linux with copy-on-write forking. When creating pthread interprocess mutex in a parent, will it be effective in the child or it will work so only if I mmap it into shared memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `fork()` the whole memory space is duplicated, including mutexes, so to answer your question, the new mutex will be a copy of the parent's mutex, so you have to `mmap` it.

Note:
You will need to set the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` flag on the mutex attribute using `pthread_mutexattr_getpshared()`.

Comment: But doesnt it work in a way, like file or socket descriptors which are duplicated and mapped to the same system resource? Or there is no kernel resource behind the pthread mutex? It is a peace of data/code in the user space?

Comment: Implementation wise I'm not sure, but it definitely looks like it's just some data that is duplicated. So the conclusion is that both processes need to have access to the same mutex, not separate copies.